# mysqldump: Got error : 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (2) when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, xampp, database-backups

I want to backup my database in `xampp`. But I can't backup with `phpMyAdmin` because my Windows 8.1 has a problem, I can't do anything when it starts. It's showing an error message about explorer not working.

So I want to know how I can backup my database with command line, I use `mini-XP` in Hiren's boot CD, using command line access to `mysql` in `xampp`.

I change directory to `e:/xamp/mysql/bin`.

I use `mysqldump` following what many websites have done. Like this :

`mysqldump --all-databases > mysqlbackup.sql`

But I recieve the following error message:

```
mysqldump: Got error : 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (2)
when trying to connect
```

[image: Image of the error message.]

Can anyone provide a solution or helping hand?

Comment: well it simply looks like your mysqld service isn't running.

Comment: e4c5, Now I want to install a new Windows but I can't do it because my database still stick in xampp. I duplicate xampp folder into my external harddrive. But I don't know after that, have anyway can I replace them in xampp folder.

Comment: if your database has not been corrupted copying the data directory will work as long as you install the exact same version of mysql next time. A newer version can also be used after following the upgrade steps